# Seeking QGIS equivalent tool/plugin of ArcMap Spatial Join within Distance

Tags: qgis-3, spatial-join, spatial-statistics

I would like to do a join by location between two point layers in QGIS 3 (3.4.10, Coruña). I would like to get the mean (or median) value of an attribute all the points of point layer 2 within a 5 meter radius of every point of point layer 1.

In ArcMap my approach would be:

- Point layer 1 & 2: **spatial join**,  fill in the field map as "Mean" for the attribute, set join as "within a distance" and fill in 5 meters.

My approch in QGIS3 would be:

- point layer 1: **Add autoincremental field** so i have a unique id for every feature
- point layer 1: **Buffer** of 5 meter
- buffered layer & point layer 2: **Join attributes by location (Summary)**, fields to summarise -> the attribute field en summaries to calculate-> mean
- Point layer 1 and summarised layer: **Join attributes by field value** on the base of the id field made in step one.

I walk through this process all the time, so I was wondering if there is a stand alone tool/plugin in QGIS3 for this?

Comment: You could create a model which does what you need.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will if no other option comes up!

Comment: And, while we're at it: Why has your QGIS workflow the steps 1 and 4?

Answer (score 4):

You can do the join and statistics computation using a virtual layer. It would help to have an ID on the `point1` layer.

The trick is to use the true distance between the point (in the CRS unit) instead of using a buffer.

If you want to keep points from `layer1` with no nearby points in `layer2`, replace the `JOIN` by a `LEFT JOIN`

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query.

```sql
select a.*, AVG(b.field1) as avg_field1, AVG(b.field2) as avg_field2
FROM myPointLayer1 a
  JOIN myPointLayer2 b
    ON ST_Distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) <= 5
GROUP BY a.id
```